# Filtered out sucess_entries String

Tags: java, pattern-matching

can you suggest me for this String "Success Entries and Failed Entries: {FAILED_ENTRIES={}, SUCCESS_ENTRIES={123=1509180522720153332, 124=1509181140480153332}}".

here i want to filter-out two Strings **1509180522720153332** and **1509181140480153332**.Can anyone suggest me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regex

```
String str = "Success Entries and Failed Entries: {FAILED_ENTRIES={}, SUCCESS_ENTRIES={123=1509180522720153332, 124=1509181140480153332}}";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=(SUCCESS_ENTRIES=\\{)).+?(?=\\})").matcher(str);
matcher.find();
str = matcher.group();
System.out.println(str);
matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\d{3}=)\\d+").matcher(str);
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

But remember that regex lookbehind/lookahead are not good in performance